# .NET Core WebAPI - Setting default authorization policy on Negotiate (Windows authentication) changes HttpContext.User type

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

If I setup Negotiate authentication (Windows/NTLM) in a .NET Core 5.0 or 3.1 WebAPI, and add a default authorization policy to require authenticated user, the type of `HttpContext.User` changes from `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` to `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`.

I can successfully reproduce this issue by following the steps below.

#### Environment:

- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10.3
- Windows 10 1909 (Build 18363.1621) on a corporate domain, using on-premise Active Directory
- .NET Core 5.0.7/.NET Core 3.1.16
- IIS Express using In Process hosting model

#### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new "ASP.NET Core WebAPI" project targeting .NET Core 5.0 or .NET Core 3.1.  For what it's worth, I used the new project wizard in Visual Studio, not the `dotnet` command.
2. Modify `launchSettings.json` to set IIS Express to **enable** Windows Authentication, and **disable** Anonymous Authentication.  Also note I have disabled SSL by setting the port number to zero (not sure if this is relevant):

   ```json
   {
     "iisSettings": {
       "windowsAuthentication": true,
       "anonymousAuthentication": false,
       "iisExpress": {
         "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:46007",
         "sslPort": 0
       }
     },
     "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
     "profiles": {
       "IIS Express": {
         "commandName": "IISExpress",
         "launchBrowser": true,
         "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
         "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" NuGet package `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` (or with .NET Core 3.1: `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate --version 3.1.16`)
4. In `Startup.cs`, add the following `using` statement:

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
   ```

   Add to `ConfigureServices()` before `services.AddControllers();`:

   ```cs
   services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();
   services.AddAuthorization();
   ```

   Before `app.UseAuthorization();` in `Configure()`, add:

   ```cs
   app.UseAuthentication();
   ```
5. To test, I added an `[Authorize]` attribute to the existing `WeatherForecastController.cs` `Get()` method, then added a simple line of code to easily debug the HttpContext.User object.  This is my code:

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

   // code removed for brevity

   [Authorize]
   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
   {
       // set a debug breakpoint to inspect this value
       var user = HttpContext.User;

       var rng = new Random();
       return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
       {
           Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
           TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
           Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
       })
       .ToArray();
   }
   ```
6. Start Visual Studio debugger with the IIS Express profile, then inspect the `HttpContext.User` object.  You will find the debugger reports this as `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`, as expected.
7. Modify `Startup.cs` to add the following default authorization policy to `services.AddAuthorization()` so the `[Authorize]` attribute requires an authenticated user.

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
   ```

   ```cs
   services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
   {
       cfg.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
           .Build();
   });
   ```
8. With no additional changes, repeat step 6.  This time inspecting the same `HttpContext.User` object, the debugger will report the type as `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`.

#### The issue

When the `HttpContext.User` is a `WindowsPrincipal`, you can use `HttpContext.User.IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\Some_Group_Name");` to determine whether or not a user is a member of a specific Active Directory group, by name.

When `HttpContext.User` is a `ClaimsPrincipal`, the `IsInRole()` function always returns false for the same group name.  Inspecting the claims, I do see where all the user's Active Directory groups are being pulled in, but can only be referenced by the SID, not the common name.

The only workaround I have found (Windows OS specific) is the following code:

```cs
new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity).IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\Some_Group_Name");
```

Why is this happening?  Is this an issue with my configuration, code, and/or environment?  How can I have a default authorization policy, but still have `HttpContext.User` as a `WindowsPrincipal` without the cast?